# I'm looking for phrases which could be used in a similar way to "Best of a bad bunch"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to find phrases i can use to label four quadrant is a graph. The one i'm struggling with is low on the x axis but high on the y axis. The best I've come up with is "best of a bad bunch" but for political reasons i'd like something without "bad" in it.

Comment: You might get better suggestions if you include some background, such was what properties are being shown on the graphs, how are the axes labelled, etc.?

Comment: Maybe just "best" on its own - if "best of a bad bunch" fits then the quadrant in question is the best one. What have you come up with for the other quadrants?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for "best person in a group of bad people"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61533/word-for-best-person-in-a-group-of-bad-people)

Comment: *best of the rest* ?

Answer (score 0):

**The least (describer) of the group**:

- The least expensive of an expensive group
- The least late of a late group
- The most developed of an underdeveloped group
- The youngest of an older group
- The lowest scorer of a low scoring group
- The least heinous in a band of thieves
- The fluffiest in a table of weak lattes
- The sun in a cloud of pale stars

They could be literal, or more fanciful/metaphoric/entertaining as in the latter examples. This may help you, if you want to or need to criticise - or at least call out the bad ones, without being critical or hurtful - which could work - as long it is done humourously but without actually poking fun.

It would, as commenters mention, help, if you told us what ‘the bunch’ *is* - since you don’t want to describe them as ‘bad’ - but ‘bad’ is the only description you have given us of them, thus far.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20least%20of